# Confidence interval for $x_0$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, linear-regression, confidence-interval

Given the following problem:

> Suppose pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ are observed independently for $i = 1,2,...,n,$ where the $x_i$’s are constants and $Y_i = g(x_i) + ε_i$ with $g(x_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i$ and the $ε_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. In the classic callibration problem discussed by Scheffe, an additional measurement, $Y_0$ is made, but no corresponding $x_0$ is available.  Find functions $L$ and $U$, depending on pairs $(x_i,Y_i)$ and $Y_0$ such that $P(L \leq x_0 \leq U)=0.95$.

I was able to find my pivot: $$\frac{Y_0 - \hat{g(x_0)}}{s\sqrt{1+x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_0}}\sim t_{n-2}$$ and so $$0.95 = P\left(-t_{n-1,0.025} \leq \frac{Y_0 - \hat{g(x_0)}}{s\sqrt{1+x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_0}}\leq t_{n-1,0.025}\right)$$

However, I am not sure how to solve this for $x_0$.

Comment: The type of each object (known/uknown, scalar/vector) and the relationship to $Y_0$ and/or  $x_0$ is not clear to me.

Comment: @Michael We have a linear regression model of type $Y=X\beta +\epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2I)$. $x_0$ is an observation outside of our n independent observations, for which we know the y-value for, $Y_0$. However, we don't know what $x_0$ observation is and we try to find a CI for it.